# Why is this twig statement is not working?

Tags: twig

Possible issue with the twig "in" statement. Here is a couple of examples:

**Why is this one working**

```
{% set curPath = 'http://example.com' %} 
{% if 'exa' in curPath %}
   Inside The If Statement
{% endif %}
```

**Why is this one Not Working?**

```
   {% set curPath =  url('<current>') %}
    {{ curPath }} // prints 'example.com' 
    {% if 'exa' in curPath %}
       Inside The If Statement
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you try `{{dump(curPath ) }}`. Prolly `url` returns an object rather than a string. By calling `{{ curPath }}` you are actually doing `{{ curPath.toString() }}`. If this is the case you could "solve" this by doing `{% if 'exa in curPath~'' %}`

Comment: 'exa in curPath~'  works for me and i did not even have to put the eva in quotation. Before you know it, Twig is going to be its own programming language if it is not that already... Thanks @DarkBee...